# Android icon not being created when I run application

Tags: android-studio

I wasn't exactly sure what to look up for this. I feel like I accidentally deleted something but when I run an app in android studio it doesn't create the shortcut icon on my device. So I cant open the app unless Android studio is open and I re-run the app. How can I make it install the app again?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your launcher or some other 'hidden app' feature you might have activated by accident.

Go to `Settings > Apps` to check if your app is installed there. If it's a launcher configuration most likely a simple reinstall isn't going to suffice, since the launcher will remember to hide the app by it's package name.

Comment: It is indeed under the Settings> App, and you were correct that a reinstall wasnt enough. Where can I go to change the launcher settings so it will create the shortcut?

Comment: It really depends on your launcher, you gotta go through it's settings and check it out...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, but are you saying it should be in the settings> app on my device? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you but the issue is specifically with one project in android studio. All other projects create the shortcut as they should. And I cant find a Settings> App in android studio so im not sure where to view my launcher settings....

Comment: I was talking about `Settings` as in the Android device settings. The launcher part really is specific to the one you're using.